# vertical aligning using display:table in bootstrap works in Chrome , not in firefox . Why?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

OK so i have the following **HTML** markup :

```
<section class="aboutus" id="aboutus">
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <span class="image-holder our-clients"></span>
                <h2>Our Clients</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, aperiam sunt reprehenderit corporis quidem libero ad officiis odio labore ratione adipisci, delectus, maxime saepe dolorem optio id dolore facilis recusandae.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

and the following **css** style that applies :

```
.aboutus{
    /*display: table !important;*/
    height: 100%;
}

.aboutus .container{
    display: table !important;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;    
}

.aboutus .row{
    display: table-row !important;
    vertical-align:middle; !important;

}

.aboutus .col-md-4{
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell !important;
    vertical-align:middle !important;
}    

.aboutus .image-holder{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 210px;
    width: 210px;
    background: url('../images/professionals.png'); 
}
```

now if you have a look at the html code you will see the following class :

```
class="aboutus"
```

which takes `100% height`(100% screen size) on any given device ,

now what i wanted to achieve was , i wanted to vertically align the part from col-md-4 onwards , in the browser.

so to sum it up :

```
<section class="aboutus" id="aboutus">
```

will take the full height of the device screen and :

```
<div class="col-md-4 text-center">
```

will perfectly **vertically-align** inside the

unfortunately the approach used my me works in chrome but not in firefox , although i am running almost latest versions of both . WHY is this happening ??

also , how good is the approach i have used cross-browser . i guess it won't work ie8 and below ? anyways , this is a supplementary question .

My main question is Why is my vertical align css code not functioning in firefox .

**EDIT ::** Below is my Prolem in a nutsheel :

[WHY Does this work in chrome but not in firefox ??](http://chopapp.com/#r8p333zh)

Thank you.

Kind regards.

Alexander

Comment: Try adding `height:100%` to `.aboutus .row`

Comment: @Vucko does't work :)

Comment: Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbmb6an5/1/) - works in FF.

Comment: @Vucko , I'll give it a go in a browser and let u knw , btw , was the only thing you changed height:100% on .aboutus . row ????

Comment: @Vucko just an update , ironically adding height:100% on `.aboutus .row` makes the vertical alignment in chrome collapse . (i mean not perform). I'll go Dig a bit more into this and be back soon .

Comment: @Vucko I think in Firefox , we need something like this , 

Height: "Hey just be the size of the content inside u ";

because i think the .row is my default taking 100% height , i just did 

Height:200px; and everything was almost perfect .. but thats obviously not what i want to be doing .. i don't like absolutes .